# When accessing remote Mercurial server I just get a printout of the hgweb.cgi python script

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mercurial

I'm trying to rebuild my Banana Pi server a catastrophic HDD failure. I have all the repositories backed up, but I'm not able to get the web server working on Armbian Linux (which is Ubuntu essentially, just for little ARM boards).

I have followed the instructions here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep

But when I go to pi/hg, whereas previously I'd get a list of all my repositories I just get the hgweb.cgi script being printed out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary
# See also http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "hgweb.config"

# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
#import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb(config)
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

And of course I can't push to the repositories form a remote machine, I get an error 404.

I *think* that script is the one I was previously running. It looks the same as the example on in the Mercurial installation, but with:

```
config = "hgweb.config"
```

So, questions are:

Does that script look right?
Should I have installed something so wsgicgi works. Should, indeed, I even be using that?
Do you need any other information to troubleshoot this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I found someone else who had a similar problem and they changed to hgweb.wsgi, so I gave that a go and it works. Maybe later version of mercurial and/or apache don't like the older method.